# protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for [token: "12345"]

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this in router.ex:

```
    get "/my_url/my_url2/:token", MySuperController, :my_action
```

When I call this:

```
<%= link("something", to: my_super_url(@conn, :my_action, token: "12345")) %>
```

I get an error:

```
protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for [token: "12345"]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the variables present in the URL pattern as direct arguments, not in a keyword list:

```
<%= link("something", to: my_super_url(@conn, :my_action, "12345")) %>
```

The keyword list at the end is meant for adding query args to the end of the URL, e.g. `my_super_url(@conn, :my_action, "12345", foo: "bar")` will return `"/my_url/my_url2/12345?foo=bar"`.